# Sectional curvature on hypersurface

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature, connections

For some hypersurface $M \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, with $n \geq 4$, I want to show that for the sectional curvature of $M$, it holds that it can't be negative.

I somehow don't know how to start here. I mean I know that:

$K(span(v,w))=\overline{K}(span(v,w))+ \Vert \nu \Vert \dfrac{<Sv,v><Sw,w>-<Sv,w>^2}{<v,v><w,w>-<v,w>^2} $

where $\overline{K}(span(v,w))$ is the sectional curvature of $\mathbb{R}^N$ and $\nu$ is the unit normal on $M$. Also, I know that $\overline{K}(span(v,w))=0$ and that $<v,v><w,w>-<v,w>^2>0$

Now $Sv=\overline{\nabla}_v \nu$ right? I just don't know how to use the properties of $\mathbb{R}^n$ here. How does the Levi-Civita connection look like for $\mathbb{R}^n$?

As a hint, I have that its possible to diagonalize $S$, but don't really understand this.

Here is also a picture of the exercise:
[image]

Comment: Is there anything special about $M$?

Comment: I don't have any further informations but it could  be implicited that $M$ is a pseudo riemannian hypersurface.. would that be useful?

Comment: What metric are you using on $\mathbb R^n$?

Comment: the standard inner product

Comment: I've also added a picture of the exercise, in case that I've let out some important information..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The diagonalization hint is a nice way to go. Since $S: T_pM\to T_pM$ is symmetric, there is a orthonormal basis for $T_pM$ with $Se_i =\lambda_i e_i$ and $\lambda_i\in\mathbb{R}$.

Now for $i\ne j$ you have $K(e_i, e_j) = \lambda_i\lambda_j$.

If some $\lambda_i$ is zero you are done (then $K(e_i, e_j) = 0$ for this $i$).

So assume you have at least three $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3$ all non-zero. Then at least two of these have the same sign (say $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$ have the same sign) and so the sectional curvature through this plane ($e_1, e_2$) will be positive.

Comment: Thanks already for the answer! There are some things I don't really understand yet: Why is $Se_i=\lambda_ie_i$ for a orthonormal basis of $T_pM$? $Se_i=\nabla_{e_i} \nu$ for the unit normal $\nu$ to $T_pM$, right?

Comment: Right, that is $S$. And one can show that $S$ is symmetric wrt the metric (here the standard inner product on $\mathbb{R}^n$). Then use that symmetric matrices have a basis of orthonormal eigenvectors (with real eigenvalues).

To show $S$ is symmetric, let $X,Y$ be vector fields along $M$, then apply $X$ to  $\langle\nu, Y\rangle = 0$, gives $\langle S(X),Y\rangle = -\langle\nu,\nabla_XY\rangle$. Now use that $[X,Y]$ is tangent to $M$ and the connection is torsion free to get $\langle S(X),Y\rangle = \langle X,S(Y)\rangle$.

Comment: Great, I understand now, thank you very much!